Error "table ... already exits" when using to_sql(...,if_exists='append') with Pandas and SQLite
Using Panadas 2.2.3, sqlite3.version 2.6.0 and python 3.12.5,
I get an error "table ... already exits" when using to_sql with if_exists='append'. I just try to append some data from a Pandas df to a SQLite DB table. Using if_exists='replace' produces the same result.
In order to make sure that the db connection is active and the columns match, I used some simple print statements in a first try block and the failing to.sql in a second try block. Also a "select statement" from the same table is used in the first block. The first block is executed without an exception and the second block throws the message 'table "groupedData" already exists': (See print('ERROR Try 2'))
Source code:
try:
    print(db_conn)
    print(table_grouped)
    data = [x.keys() for x in db_conn.cursor().execute(f'select * from {table_grouped};').fetchall()]
    print(data)
except Error as e:
    print('ERROR Try 1')
    print(e)

try: 
    print(df_grouped.head(5))
        
    df_grouped.to_sql(table_grouped, db_conn, if_exists='append', index=False) 
    #if_exists : {‘fail’, ‘replace’, ‘append’}
    db_conn.commit()

except Error as e:
    print('ERROR Try 2')
    print(e)

Output:
<sqlite3.Connection object at 0x000001C0E7C0EB60>
groupedData
[['CustomerID', 'TotalSalesValue', 'SalesDate']]
   CustomerID  TotalSalesValue  SalesDate
0       12345            400.0 2020-02-01
1       12345           1050.0 2020-02-04
2       12345             10.0 2020-02-10
3       12345            200.0 2021-02-01
4       12345             50.0 2021-02-04
ERROR Try 2
table "groupedData" already exists


Reporting the issue, I added
data = [[123, 10.0, '2020-01-01'], [123, 20.0, '2020-02-01'], [123, 15.0, '2020-03-01']] df_grouped = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['CustomerID', 'TotalSalesValue', 'SalesDate'])
for creating simple test data. Obviously, SQLite DB with according table is required to reproduce the issue.

Similar, but no answer

We can see what is happening by logging the SQL statements made by Pandas. This minimal example:
import sqlite3
from sqlite3 import Error
import pandas as pd

table_name = 'tbl'

df = pd.DataFrame([(1,)], columns=['a'])

with sqlite3.connect(':memory:') as conn:
    # Log all (successful) SQL statements.
    conn.set_trace_callback(print)

    # Create table with differently cased name.
    CREATE = """CREATE TABLE Tbl (a int)"""
    conn.execute(CREATE)

    print('*** Updating table ***')
    try:
        df.to_sql(table_name, conn, if_exists='append', index=False)
        conn.commit()
    except Error as e:
        print(e)

Produces this output:
CREATE TABLE Tbl (a int)
*** Updating table ***

        SELECT
            name
        FROM
            sqlite_master
        WHERE
            type IN ('table', 'view')
            AND name='tbl';
table "tbl" already exists

So we can see that when Pandas checks for the table's existence, it uses the exact name that is passed to to_sql(), so the existing table is not found. However when Pandas attempts to create the table, SQLite will raise an error* if a table already exists with the same case-insensitive name, as we can see in the SQLite CLI:
sqlite> CREATE TABLE T (a int);
sqlite> CREATE TABLE t (a int);
Parse error: table t already exists
  CREATE TABLE t (a int);
               ^--- error here

Arguably Pandas could check in a case-insensitive way, as described here, but equally it could be argued that it is the programmer's responsibility to use consistent names†.

* Pandas raises a ValueError if it detects that a table already exists, however the code is trapping an SQLite Error, so the exception isn't being raised by Pandas.
† In fact, it seems that this issue has been raised before, and the Pandas developers elected to not make any changes.

Thank you, @snakecharmerb, for your answer and for providing the minimal example. I did not think about simply using an in-memory SQLite DB in my question to provide a "complete" example (Sorry for my "incomplete" version) and will keep that in mind for the future.
I added issue #22821 (which you mentioned) in a comment and closed issue #59886 (that I had raised).

It turned out (thanks to a friend who does not have a stackoverflow account -yet) that the problem was case sensitivity. I named the SQLite db table GroupedData and used groupedData in Python with Pandas.
While SQL table names are usually not case-sensitive and also sqlite3 is not case-sensitive with table names...
db_conn = sqlite3.connect(db_file_path)
db_conn.cursor().execute(f'select * from {table_grouped};').fetchall()

to_sql() from Pandas shows a case sensitive behaviour with a error message not indicating the problem properly. Using table_grouped='GroupedData', the second try block worked for both append and replace.
I will report the topic to Pandas here, linking to this stackoverflow question. Either giving a more specific error message or changing the behaviour of to_sql() to be also non case-sensitive would be my suggestion.

Strange, I would have expected the "table already exists" message only if if_exists=... were omitted from the to_sql call. I can't reproduce the behaviour using the code from your GitHub issue.

@snakecharmerb. Same here. The "table already exists" with if_exists='append' was strange. I did use the code from GitHub in a single test.py file in VS Code and with cmd on Windows 11 (copy paste from file) and boths showed the issue.
SQL code to generate table:
CREATE TABLE "GroupedData" ( "CustomerID" INTEGER,   "TotalSalesValue" REAL,   "SalesDate" TIMESTAMP )
from "DB Browser (SQLite)". DB and table created here.
